# Google Sheets concatenate every columnA values with every columnB values

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation

I have this:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 |
| A2 | B2 |
| A3 | B3 |

How do I concatenate every columnA values with every columnB values with a formula (or script) to have this:

| Result |
| --- |
| A1B1 |
| A1B2 |
| A1B3 |
| A2B1 |
| A2B2 |
| A2B3 |
| A3B1 |
| A3B2 |
| A3B3 |

I did it manually with "&" but couldn't manage to find the formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```
=INDEX(FLATTEN(A1:A3&TRANSPOSE(B1:B3)))
```

- 

[image]

Incase the [new functions](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/200022527?hl=en) have rolled out for you, try:

```
=INDEX(TOCOL(TOCOL(A:A,1)&TOROW(B:B,1)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter()` to get just the non-blank values, `transpose()` to build all combinations, and finally `flatten()` to get the results in one column, like this:

```
=arrayformula( flatten( filter(A2:A, len(A2:A)) & transpose(filter(B2:B, len(B2:B))) ) )
```